# Why does this native query work when hardcoded but not with @Param?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, crud

I'm trying to run the following query

```
select * from Person where name || '|' || age in ('Fred|19','Sam|17','Chris|20')
```

Code using JPA

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    @Query(value = ":query", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Person> findAllInList(@Param("query") String query);
}
```

The above gives

```
SQL Error: 900, SQLState: 42000
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

So I did some experimenting and just hard coded the string in

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from Person where name || '|' || age in ('Fred|19','Sam|17','Chris|20')", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Person> findAllInList();
}
```

The above gives me the correct result. The query also works when running it using DBeaver and Oracle SQL developer. My original thought was that substituting parameters into 'value' using @Param is just a 1 to 1 replacement so something else must be going on.
What am I missing here to make it work as a parameter?

Comment: JPA input parameters can only be used in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause, it's not possible to pass a partial SQL expression. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_input_params).

Answer (score 1):

> My original thought was that substituting parameters into 'value' using @Param is just a 1 to 1 replacement so something else must be going on

It's not. You cannot substitute any SQL substring. [The JPA specification define where you can place parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_input_params).

If you want to pass queries as parameter,  it's easier to use a custom repository and the entity manager:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository {
 
    List<Person> findAllInList(String query);
}
    
public class PersonRepositoryImpl implements PersonRepository {
     
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
 
    @Override
    public List<Person> findAllInList(String query) {
        return entityManager
            .createNativeQuery(query, Person.class)
            .getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only easier, but also **safer**

Comment: How is this safer?