# Native query not replacing parameter and is there a JPQL version of this native query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I have a JSONB column `order_information` in Postgres table `order_information_table` with the below data:

```
{
    "response_list": [
        {
            "interest": 5,
            "number": "12221",
            "amount": 1200
        },
        {
            "interest": 1,
            "number": "12229",
            "amount": 800
        },
        {
            "interest": 2,
            "number": "12227",
            "amount": 2500
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to get the database record by searching the JSONB column value's `number` field.

When I used a native query with hardcoded number value then I see the result:

```
@Query("select * from order_information_table " +
  "where order_information -> 'response_list' @> '[{\"number\": \"12221\"}]'",
  nativeQuery = true)
fun retrieveOrdersForNumber(
  @Param("number") number: String
): List<OrderInformation>
```

But when I try to use parameter then it does not work:

```
@Query("select * from order_information_table " +
  "where order_information -> 'response_list' @> '[{\"number\": \":number\"}]'",
  nativeQuery = true)
fun retrieveOrdersForNumber(
  @Param("number") number: String
): List<OrderInformation>
```

Why is the parameter `:number` not getting replaced with the value?

Is there a JPQL query possible for this instead of using a native query?

Comment: Because it is part of a literal string (i.e. in single quotes) and that is used as is.

Comment: @M.Deinum How do I fix the native query so that the actual number from method argument is used?

Comment: Apart from String concat there is no solution I suspect as it is a literal String it will be used as is (the same with using a positional parameter will happen).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173043/why-does-this-native-query-work-when-hardcoded-but-not-with-param

Comment: @M.Deinum So I need an instance of entity manager to run a query or can I still do this with Spring data repository itself without explicity autowiring entity manager myself?

Comment: You linked to the question that has the answer on how to do that. Just autowire it is the easiest solution (unless you want to write a custom repository implementation).

Comment: With the syntax proposed in my edited answer that should do the trick since the `:number` parameter is no more in single-quoted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Laurent Schoelens, this is the native SQL query which uses [JSON Creation Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE):

```
select * from order_information_table
where order_information -> 'response_list' @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('number', '12221'))
```

And this native SQL query can be executed in Spring Data as below:

```
@Query("select * from order_information_table where " +
    "order_information -> 'response_list' @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('number', cast(:number as VARCHAR)))",
    nativeQuery = true)
  fun retrieveOrdersForNumber(
    @Param("number") number: String
  ): List< OrderInformation >
```

I think there is no JPQL query possible for this query.

Comment: Thanks for the final answer. Learned something on this one :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `number` is the first parameter, why don't you change `'[{\"number\": \":number\"}]'` to `'[{\"number\": ?1}]'`

See here : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#2-native-2

**EDIT**

After more reading, I think the error is the json part beeing quoted.

Since you're using native queries, maybe you should try using [JSON Creation Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE)

```java
@Query("select * from order_information_table " +
  "where order_information -> 'response_list' @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('number', :number))",
  nativeQuery = true)
```

When running the following json function in psql, I get the following result :

```
SELECT jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('number', '12221'));
    jsonb_build_array    
------------------------
 [{"number" : "12221"}]
```

Comment: It has the same problem as the named parameter. When I use your query I get sql error. If I use this text with quotes `'[{\"number\": \"?1\"}]'` then I get the same behaviour as the named parameter in my question i.e. the result is empty list

Comment: Ok, sorry. I think the error is the singlequoted json right element. Updated response

Comment: The new query does not run in my pgAdmin. I get error `@> json_bu...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Could you give the complete error ? It seems truncated...

Comment: Here is the db fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/zLhTWGU6. The 3rd query workds but the 4th one does not.

Comment: Updated answer, psql is waiting for string and not json as argument... Solution feels a bit hacky now, sorry 

Comment: Hi, the new queries does not seem to query the table `order_information_table`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256114/discussion-between-laurent-schoelens-and-firstpostcommenter).

Comment: The query works:- `select * from order_information_table where order_information -> 'response_list' @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('number', '12221'))`. Now I am checking if this can be formatted using parameters in Spring data. The Spring data is not working even with this query although when executed directly with hardcoded value it works